# MATLAB: doubling the occurrences of a value

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

It's hard to explain so I will show an example of what I would like to do:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5]
```

I would like the outcome to be:

```
x = [1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5]
```

Preferably without the use of a for loop, but either method would be appreciative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the Kronecker tensor product ([kron](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html?refresh=true) function) which is pretty neat:

```
x = kron(x,ones(1,2))

x =

     1     1     2     2     3     3     4     4     5     5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it sorted as you have here, you could do:

```
y = sort([x x]);
```

alternatively if the order matters:

```
y = reshape([x;x],[1,2*length(x)])
```